# Why isn't move constructor elided whenever possible with `make_x()` functions?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, move-semantics, perfect-forwarding, copy-elision

I cannot figure out why in the last case is the **move constructor called when copy elision is enabled** (or even mandatory such as in C++17):

```
class X {
  public:
    X(int i) { std::clog << "converting\n"; }
    X(const X &) { std::clog << "copy\n"; }
    X(X &&) { std::clog << "move\n"; }
};

template <typename T>
X make_X(T&& arg) {
  return X(std::forward<T>(arg));
}

int main() {
  auto x1 = make_X(1);    // 1x converting ctor invoked
  auto x2 = X(X(1));      // 1x converting ctor invoked
  auto x3 = make_X(X(1)); // 1x converting and 1x move ctor invoked
}
```

What rules hinder the move constructor to be elided in this case?

**UPDATE**

Maybe more straightforward cases when move constructors are called:

```
X x4 = std::forward<X>(X(1));
X x5 = static_cast<X&&>(X(1));
```

Comment: When do you think your move constructor is called ?

Comment: @Pumkko The output does indeed show a move constructor call http://cpp.sh/8lkmo

Comment: Have you double-checked what your compiler vendor may have to say on the subject? I suspect that some compilers may approach this a little differently to try to avoid breaking legacy code.

Comment: @SirGuy I don't think compilers have any options in C++17. I have tried GCC and Clang with `-std=c++1z`. _(For instance, initialization of `x1` and `x2` is in C++17 correct even if both copy and move ctors of `X` are deleted.)_

Comment: Have a look at the output with copy elision disabled http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/efd8922fec01bafc

Comment: @Pumkko I know exactly what happens with disabled copy elision. This is not what I am asking about.

Comment: So if i understand correctly op your question is why has the compiler been able to optimize this statement `auto x2 = X(X(1));` but not this one `auto x3 = make_X(X(1));`

Comment: `auto x2 = X(X(1));` has move as well in VS2017

Comment: @KillzoneKid Compiled against which Standard? In C++17, `auto x2 = X(X(1));` IMO **must not** invoke move ctor or even require its existence.

Comment: The copy can only be elided if the copy/move has no side effects, because your copy AND move both have side effects the compiler cannot assume they are safe.

Comment: @Mgetz That's not true, see, e.g., http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision.

Comment: @DanielLangr cppreference while a good source is NOT the standard, please quote from the standard and not a reference site.

Comment: @Mgetz Then, see C++ Standards. I believe you can find proper paragraphs by yourself (e.g. §12.8.31 in C++11).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The two cases are subtly different, and it's important to understand why. With the new value semantics in C++17, the basic idea is that we delay the process of turning prvalues into objects as long as possible.

```
template <typename T>
X make_X(T&& arg) {
  return X(std::forward<T>(arg));
}

int main() {
  auto x1 = make_X(1);
  auto x2 = X(X(1));
  auto x3 = make_X(X(1));
}
```

For `x1`, the first expression we have of type `X` is the one in the body of `make_X`, which is basically `return X(1)`. That's a prvalue of type `X`. We're initializing the return object of `make_X` with that prvalue, and then `make_X(1)` is itself a prvalue of type `X`, so we're delaying the materialization. Initializing an object of type `T` from a prvalue of type `T` means directly initializing [from the initializer](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17.6.1), so `auto x1 = make_X(1)` reduces to just `X x1(1)`.

For `x2`, the reduction is even simpler, we just directly apply the rule.

For `x3`, the scenario is different. We have a prvalue of type `X` *earlier* (the `X(1)` argument) and that prvalue binds to a reference! At the point of binding, we apply [the temporary materialization conversion](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#ref-5.2.1.sentence-2) - which means we actually create [a temporary object](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.rval). *That* object is then moved into the return object, and we can do prvalue reduction on the subsequent expression all the way. So this reduces to basically:

```
X __tmp(1);
X x3(std::move(__tmp));
```

We still have one move, but only one (we can elide chained moves). It's the binding to a reference that necessitates the existence of a separate `X` object. The argument `arg` and the return object of `make_X` must be different objects - which means a move must happen.

---

For the last two cases:

```
X x4 = std::forward<X>(X(1));
X x5 = static_cast<X&&>(X(1));
```

In both cases, we're binding a reference to a prvalue, which again necessitates the temporary materialization conversion. And then in both cases, the initializer is an xvalue, so we don't get the prvalue reduction - we just have move construction from the xvalue that was a materialized temporary object from a prvalue.

Comment: Note I have heard of a proposal (when isn't there) to greatly extend elision permission to include (among other things) the above cases.  I don't have a link or a number.

Comment: ... and can you explain why the binding to an rvalue reference, then move construction, is not treated the same as a construction of a prvalue constructed from a prvalue? I mean, why was the second deemd worthy of elision and the other unworthy?  @Yakk asking you to comment on this as well if you feel like it.

Comment: @einpoklum Because the standard lets you elide in narrow circumstances, and that isn't one of them?  An rvalue reference is not a prvalue.  A prvalue is a kind of rvalue.  Elision can occur when constructing an object from a prvalue, plus the NRVO and some exception based cases.

Comment: Yeah, your first sentences rings true. Antony Polukhin has also been saying the same and trying to push a proposal for expanding the circumstances.

Answer (score 5):

Because in the expression `X(std::forward<T>(arg))`, even if, in the last case, `arg` is a reference bound to a temporary, it is still not a temporary. Inside the function body, the compiler cannot ensure that `arg` is not bound to an lvalue. Consider what would happen if the move constructor was elided and you would perform this call:

```
auto x4 = make_X(std::move(x2));
```

`x4` would become an alias for `x2`.

The rules for move elision of the return value is described in [[class.copy]/32](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/class.copy#31):

> [...]This elision of copy/move operations, called copy elision, is permitted in the following circumstances (which may be combined to eliminate multiple copies):
>
> - in a return statement in a function with a class return type, when the expression is the name of a non-volatile automatic object (other than a function or catch-clause parameter) with the same cv-unqualified type as the function return type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing the automatic object directly into the function's return value
> - when a temporary class object that has not been bound to a reference ([class.temporary]) would be copied/moved to a class object with the same cv-unqualified type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing the temporary object directly into the target of the omitted copy/move

In the call `make_X(X(1))` copy elision actualy happens, but only once:

1. First X(1) creates a temporary that is bound to `arg`.
2. Then `X(std::forward<T>(arg))` invokes the move constructor. `arg` is not a temporary so the second rule above does not apply.
3. Then the result the expression `X(std::forward<T>(arg))` should also be moved to construct the return value but this move is elided.

---

About your UPDATE, `std::forward` cause materialisation of the temporary `X(1)` that is bound to an xvalue: the return of `std::forward`. This returned xvalue is not a temporary so copy/elision is not anymore applicable.

Again what would happen in this case if move elision occured. (The c++ grammar is not contextual):

```
auto x7 = std::forward<X>(std::move(x2));
```

---

Nota: After I have seen a new answer about C++17 I wanted to add to confusion.

In C++17, the definition of `prvalue` is that changed that there are not any more any move constructor to elide inside your example code. Here example of [result code](https://godbolt.org/g/AigACV) of GCC with the option `fno-elide-constructors` in C++14 and then in C++17:

```
#c++ -std=c++14 -fno-elide-constructors | #c++ -std=c++17 -fno-elide-constructors
main:                                   | main:
  sub rsp, 24                           |   sub rsp, 24
  mov esi, 1                            |   mov esi, 1
  lea rdi, [rsp+15]                     |   lea rdi, [rsp+12]
  call X::X(int)                        |   call X::X(int)
  lea rsi, [rsp+15]                     |   lea rdi, [rsp+13]
  lea rdi, [rsp+14]                     |   mov esi, 1
  call X::X(X&&)                        |   call X::X(int)
  lea rsi, [rsp+14]                     |   lea rdi, [rsp+15]
  lea rdi, [rsp+11]                     |   mov esi, 1
  call X::X(X&&)                        |   call X::X(int)
  lea rdi, [rsp+14]                     |   lea rsi, [rsp+15]
  mov esi, 1                            |   lea rdi, [rsp+14]
  call X::X(int)                        |   call X::X(X&&)
  lea rsi, [rsp+14]                     |   xor eax, eax
  lea rdi, [rsp+15]                     |   add rsp, 24
  call X::X(X&&)                        |   ret               
  lea rsi, [rsp+15]
  lea rdi, [rsp+12]
  call X::X(X&&)
  lea rdi, [rsp+13]
  mov esi, 1
  call X::X(int)
  lea rsi, [rsp+13]
  lea rdi, [rsp+15]
  call X::X(X&&)
  lea rsi, [rsp+15]
  lea rdi, [rsp+14]
  call X::X(X&&)
  lea rsi, [rsp+14]
  lea rdi, [rsp+15]
  call X::X(X&&)
  xor eax, eax
  add rsp, 24
  ret
```

Comment: IANALL, but still: "a reference bound to a temporary... is still not a temporary" <- uh, yeah it is; the reference is quite temporary, just like in the `x(x(1))` case where without ellision we should be calling the copy ctor for the second `x`. " Inside the function body, the compiler cannot ensure that arg is not bound to an lvalue." <- but it can inline that function and probably is doing so already.

Answer (score 4):

To simplify your example:

```
auto x1 = make_X(1);                // converting
auto x2 = X(X(1));                  // converting
auto x4 = X(std::forward<X>(X(1))); // converting + move
```

From the cppreference's [copy elision documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) (emphasis mine):

**Before c++17:**

> Under the following circumstances, the compilers are permitted, but
>   not required to omit the copy- and move- (since C++11)construction of
>   class objects ...
>
> - If a **function returns a class type by value**, and the return
>     statement's expression is the name of a non-volatile object with
>     automatic storage duration, which isn't a function parameter, or a
>     catch clause parameter, and which has the same type (ignoring
>     top-level cv-qualification) as the return type of the function, then
>     copy/move (since C++11) is omitted. When that local object is
>     constructed, it is constructed directly in the storage where the
>     function's return value would otherwise be moved or copied to. This
>     variant of copy elision is known as NRVO, "named return value
>     optimization".

**Since c++17:**

> Under the following circumstances, the compilers are required to omit
>   the copy- and move- construction...
>
> a) In initialization, if the initializer expression is a prvalue and the
>   cv-unqualified version of the source type is the same class as the
>   class of the destination, the initializer expression is used to
>   initialize the destination object:
>
> ```
> T x = T(T(T())); // only one call to default constructor of T, to initialize x
> ```
>
> b) In a function call, if the operand of a **return statement is a *prvalue***
>   and the return type of the function is the same as the type of that
>   prvalue.
>
> ```
> T f() { return T{}; }
> T x = f();         // only one call to default constructor of T, to initialize x
> T* p = new T(f()); // only one call to default constructor of T, to initialize *p
> ```

In any case `std::forward` does not fit requirements, because it's result is an *xvalue*, not a *prvalue*: it does not return class type by value. Thus no elision happens.

Comment: That must be why `auto x4 = X(std::move(X(1)));` also results in a "convert" and "move".